# Unable to import term_meta in wordpress using wp_cron

Tags: terms, term-meta

I have imported **cities** as term named as **sf-cities** I'm trying to add **countries name** as term meta I have attached sample of my code.

```
add_action( 'event_notification', 'import_countries', 10, 0 );
function import_countries(){
    $response = wp_remote_get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/russ666/all-countries-and-cities-json/master/countries.json');
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $countries = json_decode($response_body);
    
    $last_id = 0;
    
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'sf-cities',
         'hide_empty' => false,
    )); 
    $count = 1;
    foreach($countries as $country => $cities) {
        foreach($cities as $city) {
            $term = get_term_by('name', $city, 'sf-cities');
            if( $count == 1000 ) {
                $count = 1;
                usleep(500);
            }
            if(!empty( $term )) {
                if( $term->term_id > 220 ) { 
                    if( empty( get_term_meta( $term->term_id , 'country', true) )) {
                        add_term_meta( $term->term_id ,'country', $country );       
                    } else {
                        update_term_meta( $term->term_id ,'country', $country );        
                    }
                    
                } 
                $last_id = $term->term_id;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $last_id;
}
```

Even it was working in the json file there are 80k records in there. Is there any other possibility to add term meta value without cron job.

Comment: Why do you have to import it using a cron job? It's better to import it in a custom plugin. So that when you activate the plugin, these will be imported, and if you uninstall the plugin, these will be removed.

Comment: For updates, you may just implemnet an update button within the Plugin to re-run the process.

Comment: I am using service finder theme in this theme they are using the terms for storing city and country value. Thats why I create cron job for import the content.

Comment: here is the link for the theme I have using.  https://themeforest.net/item/service-finder-service-and-business-listing-wordpress-theme/15208793